# OpenGL 1.4, сцена перемещается при изменении центра вращения

Tags: c++, opengl

при помощи следующего кода рисую сцену, но при изменении центра вращения объекты на сцене съезжают(сдвиг сцены по осям), помогите пожалуйста разобраться как избежать этого эффекта

```
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z);
glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z);
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x-xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y+yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z+zTrans);
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x+xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y-yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z-zTrans);
glTranslated( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans);
```

Центр вращения меняется в интерактивном режиме.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам стоит пересмотреть порядок применения преобразований. Так же использовать разные режимы матриц. Для установки камеры GL_PROJECTION, для преобразования объектов GL_MODELVIEW матрицы.

Comment: Пересматривал порядок преобразований, не помогло. Я думаю надо какой-то компенсационный коэффициент внести, который будет подавлять скачок.

Answer (score 0):

у меня в движке для объекта преобразования высчитываются следующим образом

```
        Vector3f bX = m_rotation.getAX() * m_scale.x;
        Vector3f bY = m_rotation.getAY() * m_scale.y;
        Vector3f bZ = m_rotation.getAZ() * m_scale.z;
        Vector3f orig = m_rotation.rotate(m_origin * m_scale);
        m_transform= Transform (
                                    Vector4f(bX.x, bX.y, bX.z, 0),
                                    Vector4f(bY.x, bY.y, bY.z, 0),
                                    Vector4f(bZ.x, bZ.y, bZ.z, 0),
                                    Vector4f(m_position.x - orig.x, m_position.y - orig.y, m_position.z - orig.z, 1)
                                );
```

просто вы зря столько преобразований выполняете, ибо каждое из них это перемножение матриц, что не очень быстро.

а так можно будет просто сгенерировать матрицу и загрузить ее посредством glLoadMatrixf/glUniformMatrix4fv. m_rotation в моем случае - кватернион, задающий вращение, они очень хорошо подходят для этого

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ, учту Ваши замечания, но проблема со сдвигом наверное останется.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, победить скачек я не смог, но смог перенести выбранную точку в центр экрана, для этого ввел три новых переменных dx, dy, dz, которые вычисляются при смене центра вращения:

```
T = newCenter - oldCenter;
dx += T.x;
dy += T.y;
dz += T.z;
xTrans = yTrans = zTrans = 0;
```

Отрисовка такая:

```
glTranslated(-dx,-dy,-dz);
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z);
glScaled( scale, scale, scale );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z);
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x-xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y+yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z+zTrans);
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x+xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y-yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z-zTrans);
glTranslated( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans );
```